# get field value from Formik & Material UI form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I am trying to disable a checkbox group based on the value of a radio group. I followed the method used in the last part of the [Formik tutorial](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#leveraging-react-context). Using react context removes a lot of clutter from the form itself but I'm not sure how to expose some values now.

In the form below, in the `CheckboxGroup` component, I'm attempting to print the word `disabled` as an attribute of `checkbox1` if `radio4`'s value is "yes". I'm not sure what value should be used here as `fields` doesn't work. How do I pass a value to the form given the React Context method used?

The form:

```
export default function HealthAssessmentForm() {
    
  return (

          <Formik
              initialValues={{
                  radio4: '',
                  symptoms: '',
              }}
        
              onSubmit={async (values) => {
                  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
              }}
              validator={() => ({})}
          >
                  <Form>
                
                  <RadioInputGroup
                          label="Disable the checkbox?"
                          name="radio4"
                          options={['Yes','No']}
                      />
                      
                      <CheckboxGroup
                          {(fields.radio4.value === "yes") ? "disabled" : null}
                        name="checkbox1"
                        options={[
                            {name:"hello",label:"hello"},
                            {name:"there",label:"there"},
                            
                          ]}
                      />
                      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </Form>
          </Formik>
    )
}
```

I'm not sure the custom components are relevant here but...

```
const RadioInputGroup = (props) => {
    
    const [field, meta] = useField({...props, type:'radio'});
    return (
        <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormLabel component="legend">{props.label}</FormLabel>
            <RadioGroup aria-label={props.name} name={props.name} value={props.value}>
                <FieldArray name="options">
                    {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                        props.options.length > 0 && props.options.map((option,index) => (
                            <FormControlLabel key={index} {...props}  value={option.toLowerCase()} control={<Radio />} label={option} />
                        ))
                    )}
                </FieldArray>
            </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
    )
};

const CheckboxGroup = (props) => {
    const [field, meta] = useField({...props, type: 'checkbox', });
    return (
        <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormLabel component="legend">{props.label}</FormLabel>
            <FormGroup>
                <FieldArray name="options">
                    {({ insert, remove, push}) => (
                        props.options.length > 0 && props.options.map((option,index) => (
                            
                            <FormControlLabel
                                {...field} {...props}
                                key={index}
                                control={<Checkbox />}
                                label={option.label}
                            />
                            ))
                    )}
                </FieldArray>
                
            </FormGroup>
            <FormHelperText>Be careful</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the whole `<Form>` in a function that passes `props` as an argument. I then get access to `props.values.radio1`. However, that has exposed that radio1 does not have a value even when it is clicked, which should be a separate issue.

```
{(props) => (
     <Form>
<RadioInputGroup
   label="Disable the checkbox?"
    name="radio4"
   options={['Yes','No']}
/>
                      
                      <CheckboxGroup
                        disabled={props.values.radio1 === "No"}
                        name="checkbox1"
                        options={[
                            {name:"hello",label:"hello"},
                            {name:"there",label:"there"},
                            
                          ]}
                      />     </Form>
)}
```